Princess doll searches for real world prince
Ok so this is the plot that may have come from an anime movie:
Opening is a blonde girl is with toys that are battered and dirty and worm out. Maybe because in the real world people are abandoning and forgetting their toys?
  She tells them she'll be back.
 She's probably the princess and goes into the human world. Then the next scene is a toy store, there we see a similar doll to the girl. And the doll begins to move. She the doll and becomes live size. 
  Goes to school to search for her dream prince that will also help her defeat evil in her world ? 
  She spies a cute blonde guy who played soccer? 
  She stays after school to see him in practice. 
  She has a red stone that will help him teleport to the toy world. She accidentally drops it somewhere in the field ... and then some other guy picked it up instead and he gets teleported instead. She screams noo! But there is nothing she can do so she goes back to the toy world. 
 And towards the end she kisses him and starts to love him but he wipes off her kiss and she gets angry and starts chasing him.

Sounds like The Toy Warrior from 2005. From an online synopsis:

The Land Of Toys is a world of pure imagination, ruled by the popular doll Princess Sherbet, but when the mysterious Dark One threatens Sherbet's toy kingdom, she turns to the real world in search of a heroic Warrior Prince... unfortunately, she ends up with the imaginative trouble-maker Jinoo.  When Jinoo accidentally touches Sherbet's magical Warrior Stone, the spunky sixth-grader is suddenly transported to the Land Of Toys to become the powerful Toy Warrior!

At first, Sherbet thinks her prince is a blonde boy who's about to touch a magical gem on a soccer field and be transported to the toy world, but Jinoo touches it instead. But you either remembered the colors wrong or you saw a different version, because Sherbet is a redhead and the gem is blue. In the end, after Jinoo prevails, Sherbet kisses him on the cheek, he blushes and wipes it off and she gets angry and starts chasing him. 
Here are the first few minutes:




Omg!! The thanks for the help!! This is the movie ive been searching for!
